# How to call a python script from a .net project

Tags: python, c#, .net

I have a python project back-end with a c# GUI front-end both in the same solution. 
The python project uses libraries such as opencv, dlib etc. 
How and what is the best way to start the python script from my c# project and also have communications between them. The python project has to accept arguments for startup and continuously transmit information back to the c# project.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use something like sockets in python to continuously transmit the data to c#.

Or you could also try to make a REST API using Flask and then have your C# GUI make an HTTP GET/POST request to your Flask Endpoint with the required arguments, after the processing is done in python, you can return the response as a JSON and render it in your GUI.

You can check out the Flask Docs, its easy to get started with it.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Comment: Yes that are some great ideas thank you, but how would i spin up the python project through my c# code?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute python code by Process.start in c# project.
For example:
[ExecutePythonScript](https://medium.com/@ernest.bonat/using-c-to-run-python-scripts-with-machine-learning-models-a82cff74b027)

Comment: Is there a way to run it that keeps the current python environment as i have it in this specific project?

Answer (score 1):

You can start the Python script with Process Start like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public void StartProcess()
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processStartInfo.FileName = "your_python_path";
        var script = "your_script_path";

        processStartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{script}\"";
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    }
```